# Working with custom mailboxes and persistent actors with AtLeastOnceDelivery

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

**Questions**

1. How do you get the and log messages in the `receiveCommand` of a persistent
   actor with `AtLeastOnceDelivery` inside a custom mailbox enqueue and dequeue?

   2. How do you get the name of the persistent actor inside your custom mailbox enqueue and dequeue?

I have a custom mailbox with the following `MessageQueue:`

The issue is that messages received by a persistent actor in the `receiveCommand` are not logged at all in the dequeue or in the enqueue. Only the persisting is logged.
Additionally, the `owner.get.path.name` in my code below never gets the persistent actor's names. It gets names like `recoveryPermitter` and `inmemory-snapshot-store`.

```
class CustomMailbox(val backend: MessageQueue, owner: Option[ActorRef], system: Option[ActorSystem]) extends MessageQueue {

    override def enqueue(receiver: ActorRef, handle: Envelope): Unit = {
        // Simulate DROP
        println(s"messageType in  ${owner.get.path.name}"+handle.message.getClass.toString)
        val canEnqueue = Math.random() > 0.95
        println(s"enqueing for ${owner.get.path}: $handle")
        backend.enqueue(receiver, handle)
    }

    override def dequeue(): Envelope = {
        val mb:UnboundedMailbox.MessageQueue = backend.asInstanceOf[UnboundedMailbox.MessageQueue]
        val peek = mb.queue.peek()
        println(s"peeking for ${owner.get.path.name}: $peek")
        if(peek != null) {
            println(s"messageType in degueue ${owner.get.path.name}"+peek.message.getClass.toString)
            val canDequeue = Math.random() > 0.9
                println(s"dequeing for ${owner.get.path}: $peek")
                backend.dequeue()
        }

        else
        {
            null
        }
    }

    override def numberOfMessages: Int = backend.numberOfMessages

    override def cleanUp(owner: ActorRef, deadLetters: MessageQueue): Unit = backend.cleanUp(owner, deadLetters)

    override def hasMessages: Boolean = backend.hasMessages
}
```

For example, I have an persistent actor with the name `childclient` and the below `receiveCommand` and `updateState` methods: My enqueue and dequeue in my custom mailbox above would log something like:

Enqueueing

```
 enqueing for akka://WebShop/system/inmemory-journal: Envelope(WriteMessages(Vector(AtomicWrite(List(PersistentImpl(Goods(goods,5),1,my-Client-id,,false,Actor[akka://WebShop/user/webShopActor#-659139690],be7c37ad-9c0e-4d77-84ec-d9fd94b5f623)))),Actor[akka://WebShop/user/webShopActor/clientChild#-1139440822],2),Actor[akka://WebShop/user/webShopActor/clientChild#-1139440822])
```

dequeueing/peeking

```
peeking for inmemory-journal: 
Envelope(WriteMessages(Vector(AtomicWrite(List(PersistentImpl(Goods(goods,5),1,my-Client-id,,false,Actor[akka://WebShop/user/webShopActor#-659139690],be7c37ad-9c0e-4d77-84ec-d9fd94b5f623)))),Actor[akka://WebShop/user/webShopActor/clientChild#-1139440822],2),Actor[akka://WebShop/user/webShopActor/clientChild#-1139440822])
```

This shows that the mailbox is processing the persisting the `Goods` event after receiving the `BuyGoods` command message in my `ChildClient`. It only logs the persisting of `Goods` but it does not log the enqueuing or dequeuing(peeking) of `BuyGoods`.

```
 def updateState(evt: Evt): Unit = evt match {
    case ReduceBalance(deliveryId, amount) if state.CashBal - amount < 0 ⇒
      confirmDelivery(deliveryId)
      throw InsufficientBalance(s"Client cannot withdraw $amount from ${state.CashBal}")
    case e: ReduceBalance ⇒ state = ClientState(state.CashBal - e.amount)
      confirmDelivery(e.deliveryId)
      deliver(paymentsActor)(deliveryId => PaymentMessage(deliveryId, e.amount))
    case e: Goods =>
      deliver(stockActor)(deliveryId => ReduceStock(deliveryId, e.name, e.amount))
    case e: AddCredit =>
      state = ClientState(state.CashBal + e.amount)
    case e: PaymentAccepted =>
      log.info("client confirmed payment:" + e)
      confirmDelivery(e.deliveryId)
  }


  override def receiveCommand: Receive = {
    //request for goods from stockActor

    case c: BuyGoods =>
      log.info("Client Recieved: " + c)
      persistAsync(Goods(c.name, c.Amount))(updateState)
    //payments actor confirms payment

  }
```

Comment: see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212892/error-trying-to-make-a-persistent-actor-require-a-custom-mail-box-with-requiresm/55213727#55213727