# Error trying to make a persistent actor require a custom mail box with RequiresMessageQueue

Tags: scala, akka

I try the following:

```
class ClientActor (stockActor: ActorSelection, paymentsActor: ActorSelection) extends PersistentActor
  with AtLeastOnceDelivery with akka.actor.ActorLogging with RequiresMessageQueue[akka.custom.CustomMailbox]{
//actor implementation

}
```

I get the error:

```
illegal inheritance;

     self-type Shopping.ClientActor does not conform to akka.dispatch.RequiresMessageQueue[akka.custom.CustomMailbox]'s selftype akka.dispatch.RequiresMessageQueue[akka.custom.CustomMailbox]
      with AtLeastOnceDelivery with akka.actor.ActorLogging with RequiresMessageQueue[akka.custom.CustomMailbox]{
```

The same works with a non persistent actor:

```
    class PaymentsActor extends Actor with akka.actor.ActorLogging with RequiresMessageQueue[akka.custom.CustomMailbox] {
    // actor implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tracing the relevant source code, `PersistentActor` extends `Eventsourced` which extends [PersistenceStash](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.20/akka-persistence/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/Persistence.scala#L118) which, in turn, extends [trait Stash](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.20/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Stash.scala#L56):

```
trait Stash extends UnrestrictedStash with RequiresMessageQueue[DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics]
```

As noted in the source code:

> Note that the `Stash` trait can only be used together with actors that
>   have a deque-based mailbox. By default Stash based actors request a
>   Deque based mailbox since the stash trait extends
>   `RequiresMessageQueue[DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics]`.
>   You can override the default mailbox provided when
>   `DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics` are requested via config
>   ...

One approach would be to configure your custom mailbox similar to what is suggested in the source code remarks:

```
akka.actor.mailbox.requirements {
  "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics" = your-custom-mailbox
}
```

Comment: This was giving me a lot of headache. I had two other questions on this but I guess this was the best way of asking the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190121/how-do-you-make-a-custom-mailbox-for-both-persistent-and-non-persistent-akka-act  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55174810/working-with-custom-mailboxes-and-persistent-actors-with-atleastoncedelivery

Comment: I am still missing something. I added the above configuration to my config file but my custom mailbox still does not log the persistent actors commands received in the `receiveCommand`. I do not use the `RequiresMessageQueue` now. I thought this would work. What could I be doing wrong? The links above show what I am attempting to do in my custom mailbox

Comment: My custom mailbox now has the DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics mixin

Comment: While it is possible to mixin my persistent `ClientActor` with `RequiresMessageQueue[DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics]` it is throws an error with my custom mailbox (`RequiresMessageQueue[akka.custom.CustomMailbox])` despite the fact that my custom mailbox has a `DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics` mixin. Also, is it really possible to intercept commands to persistent actors (`receiveCommand`messages) and how?

Comment: @Gakuo, it looks like you might be hitting a relevant [RequiresMessageQueue issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18553) which apparently remains open.